# iOS Swift: Could not find intent for LiveActivity Button

Tags: ios, swift

I show some content in LiveActivity Dynamic Island and added a button. As buttons work with App Intent I created an Intent. When the button is clicked I get the following error

> Could not find an intent with identifier MyIntent, mangledTypeName: Optional("19LiveWidgetExtension10MyIntentV")

MyIntent.swift

```
import Foundation
import AppIntents

struct MyIntent: LiveActivityIntent {
     
    public init() { }
    
    func perform() async throws -> some IntentResult {
        print("click")
        return .result()
    }
}
```

MyLiveActivity.swift

```
... 
DynamicIslandExpandedRegion(.bottom) {
                    HStack(alignment: .top) {
                                            Button(intent: MyIntent()) {
                                                Image(systemName: "bolt.fill")
                                            }
                                        }
                                        .tint(.white)
                                        .padding()
                }
....
```

How can I register the Intent? Do I have to put something in the plist file? Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

It is very strange, but the problem was solved after I renamed the project folder to something else.